# Template in C with #define

Tags: c, templates, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I hope you are doing well.

I am trying to achieve implementing template functions in C with #defines. It works like a charm but I have a big issue where I couldnt find a solution yet.

First, I will show a simple RingBuffer "class" in C.

```
#define RING_BUFFER(TYPE, ARRAYSIZE)                        \
typedef struct                                                      \
{                                                                   \
    uint8_t GetElementFromPos;                                      \
    uint8_t AddElementInPos;                                        \
    TYPE Data[ARRAYSIZE];                                           \
}RingBuffer_##TYPE;                                     \
                                                                    \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Ctor(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me)\
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Reset(me);                          \
}                                                                   \
                                                                    \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Push(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me, TYPE const addData)  \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    if(me->AddElementInPos >= ARRAYSIZE)                            \
    {                                                               \
        me->AddElementInPos = 0;                                    \
    }                                                               \
                                                                    \
    me->Data[me->AddElementInPos++] = addData;                      \
}                                                                   \
                                                                    \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Pop(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me, TYPE *const getData)  \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
    ASSERT(getData != NULL)                                         \
                                                                    \
    *getData = me->Data[me->GetElementFromPos++];                   \
                                                                    \
    if(me->GetElementFromPos >= ARRAYSIZE)                          \
    {                                                               \
        me->GetElementFromPos = 0;                                  \
    }                                                               \
}                                                                   \
                                                                    \
bool_t RingBuffer_##TYPE##_IsEmpty(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me) \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    return (me->AddElementInPos == me->GetElementFromPos);          \
}                                                                   \
                                                                    \
bool_t RingBuffer_##TYPE##_IsFull(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me)  \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    return ((me->AddElementInPos+1 == me->GetElementFromPos)        \
        || ((me->GetElementFromPos == 0)                            \
        && (me->AddElementInPos == ARRAYSIZE)));                    \
}                                                                   \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Reset(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me)     \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    me->GetElementFromPos = 0;                                      \
    me->AddElementInPos = 0;                                        \
    memset(me->Data, 0, sizeof(me->Data));                          \
}
```

My issue is, that I can´t instanciate a RingBuffer with the same type in different .c files.
I am getting a linker error like "multiple definition of `RingBuffer_float_Ctor".

In C++ we can create multiple template Instances with same type and the code is created from the compiler only once.
How can I achieve this in C language?

I know, that I can add a NAME or MODULE_NAME as #define Parameter but this solution is bad because we create same identical functions with same types but different names. This is waste of memory.

Comment: Just don't do it? Put all your instantiations for standard types in a separate file.

Comment: You may not use `RING_BUFFER` in .h files. You should split `RING_BUFFER` into `RING_BUFFER_DECL` and `RING_BUFFER_IMPL` and use them in .h and .c respectively.

Comment: Or declare the functions `static inline`?

Comment: Perhaps You should limit RingBuffer scope to single source file as all functions in C are declared extern. In general it is bad design to put such implementation into macro. Elegant approach would be to create separate module. This will be spotted as very risky practice when some tools for static analysis will be used in Your project and conformance to MISRA guidelines will be required.
Is there any specific use case why You decided to pick macro and not modular implementation?

Comment: I choosed a makro implementation to try and learn doing template programming in c. Of course I can implement lots of rimgbuffers for different types, but then I get multiple files with same functionalities. Maybe I can be independentend from datatype with void pointers but this is more difficult to apply

Comment: If you want C++ facilities, you'll find the C++ compiler provides them better than a C compiler does.  You have to adjust your expectations and adapt your implementation to suit the limitations of your C compiler.  There are a number of ways to achieve what you're after.  None of the mechanisms are as simple to use (or implement) as the mechanism provided by the C++ compiler.

Comment: Just as a side note: Two ring buffers of the same type but with different size will collide, same name but differing members (well, one, to be precise).

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1: split the macro into 2. One for the header declaration, One for the source implementation. i.e.

*for the header file*

```cpp
#define RING_BUFFER_DECL(TYPE, ARRAYSIZE)                        \
typedef struct                                                      \
{                                                                   \
    uint8_t GetElementFromPos;                                      \
    uint8_t AddElementInPos;                                        \
    TYPE Data[ARRAYSIZE];                                           \
}RingBuffer_##TYPE; \
\
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Ctor(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me); \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Push(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me, TYPE const addData); \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Pop(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me, TYPE *const getData);  \
bool_t RingBuffer_##TYPE##_IsFull(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me);\
bool_t RingBuffer_##TYPE##_IsEmpty(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me);\
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Reset(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me); \
```

*For the source file*

```cpp
#define RING_BUFFER_IMPL(TYPE, ARRAYSIZE)                        \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Ctor(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me)  \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Reset(me);                          \
}                                                                   \
                                                                    \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Push(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me, TYPE const addData)  \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    if(me->AddElementInPos >= ARRAYSIZE)                            \
    {                                                               \
        me->AddElementInPos = 0;                                    \
    }                                                               \
                                                                    \
    me->Data[me->AddElementInPos++] = addData;                      \
}                                                                   \
                                                                    \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Pop(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me, TYPE *const getData)  \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
    ASSERT(getData != NULL)                                         \
                                                                    \
    *getData = me->Data[me->GetElementFromPos++];                   \
                                                                    \
    if(me->GetElementFromPos >= ARRAYSIZE)                          \
    {                                                               \
        me->GetElementFromPos = 0;                                  \
    }                                                               \
}                                                                   \
                                                                    \
bool_t RingBuffer_##TYPE##_IsEmpty(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me) \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    return (me->AddElementInPos == me->GetElementFromPos);          \
}                                                                   \
                                                                    \
bool_t RingBuffer_##TYPE##_IsFull(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me)  \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    return ((me->AddElementInPos+1 == me->GetElementFromPos)        \
        || ((me->GetElementFromPos == 0)                            \
        && (me->AddElementInPos == ARRAYSIZE)));                    \
}                                                                   \
void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Reset(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me)     \
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    me->GetElementFromPos = 0;                                      \
    me->AddElementInPos = 0;                                        \
    memset(me->Data, 0, sizeof(me->Data));                          \
}
```

Then to use:

```cpp
// In ringbuffer_int.h
RING_BUFFER_DECL(int, 512);
```

```cpp
// In ringbuffer_int.c
#include "ringbuffer_int.h"
RING_BUFFER_IMPL(int, 512);
```

### Option 2: Make all the methods static inline

```cpp
/* snip */

static inline void RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Ctor(RingBuffer_##TYPE *const me)\
{                                                                   \
    ASSERT(me != NULL)                                              \
                                                                    \
    RingBuffer_##TYPE##_Reset(me);                          \
}      

/* snip */
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can solve your linker error, by making your functions `static` (so there will be one such definiction per compilation unit, and as they will not be exported the linker will have no problem selecting which one is the one you want --as they are not exported, they are not known to the linker--)  But this will make your code larger as the functions will be actually there, repeated for each compilation unit they appear on.

As you cannot know if there's another instance of the same function defined in another compilation unit (which has been, by definition, compiled separately) there's no other solution to this problem, using legacy compilers.

There's an option that allows you to do that (a gcc compilation options allows you to define a functions as weak, so the linker will select it only if there's no alternative, and this allows you to have several definitions finally end in the program)

There's a more interesting solution  that is borrowed from the real templates used in C++ (which has the same problem, indeed, but is hidden from the programmer as it is solved by both, the compiler and linker), that allows the linker to consider that there will be several instantiations *of the same function* (those functions appear as compilation results from C++ templates, resulting in the same types and solves the problem in C++ ---well, gcc is a c++ compiler too)  This requires you to use a compilation option to indicate that the function will appear possibly in other compilation units, and a linker options that tells it to delete all except the last definitions of the same functions from the final executable.

You will need to read GCC or CLANG documentation for this (as both implement the same thing similarly) but I cannot help you on this, I have read it long time ago and know it exists, but I have not used it recently and have not the time required to prepare you an example here.  If I get the time, I'll expand my answer to illustrate how to compile/link your code.